# How can I manage a non-src module with intellij 13?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently switched from eclipse. With eclipse, I was used to have "non-src" projects (General->Simple Projects) in my workspace. They were pretty handy, since I could use them for version control of documentations, configure servers, ...)

Now with intellij, I am missing this feature. I only can import src modules into my project, otherwise I get the warning "nothing to import". Any idea how to trick intellij to accept a plain old file system directory?

Update:
To clarify, this is my setup:

```
root (trunk, sync with svn)
+- maven-project (root pom.xml)
|+- module a
|+- module b
|\- ...
+- documentation
|\- word/xls/...
\- server
 \- jboss home dir
```

I sync (update) directly on "root" to keep everything together.
I imported the structure to intellij, but only got the "maven-project" (with all submodules), not "documentation" nor "server".

I would like to have the folders next to "maven-project" in my project structure. That way, I could easily edit server settings files within idea for example or add/commit new office files without using extra tools or cli.

Hope this helps to get the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info Jan - can you please look in Settings -> Project Settings -> Version Control and see if there is a single Directory named `<Project>` ?

Comment: Yes, there is. How did you know :-)

Comment: And you checked out from the root (`trunk`), right? Weird that `documentation` doesnt get synced as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no kind of "Empty Module" or "Facet-less Module" in IntelliJ.

In such cases I just create a static **"Web"** project, as I think this is the least invasive type for modules, which doesn't need any facet:

1. File -> New Module
2. Static Web -> Web
3. At "Content Root" -> Point to your sources

Answer (score 0):

Can you bypass the import feature and just create a new module, and then copy the contents in there?

Otherwise, do you really need a module at all? Folders can quite happily sit in the file structure of your intellij project without being modules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an example setup to my question, could you please show me how I would have to use the "new module" or "folder" option with my setup?

Comment: Since the trunk is no module, I don't see the folder in the project structure, so this doesn't work ...